# Distributing an unsigned app & signing at customer end

Tags: ios, code-signing

I have a problem distributing the application. The client requirement is:

1. He wants the application to be in distribution mode (Enterprise App Store a/c), but does not want to give me the distribution certificate.
2. He wants to sign the application at his end.
3. I don't want to give the code to him

I have read few links on creating an unsigned app, and then signing it. But not very sure about it.

Can someone give a solution?

Just a note, that I have an Enterprise App Store a/c of my own. Can I create a build with my certificates and can the customer, re-sign with his Enterprise App Store certificates

Comment: not a very trusting relationship :)  This will happen every time you make updates..